# get latest activity from linkedin into website

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I am trying to get latest 3 public activities of our company from linkedin to put into a  website and i found on linkedIn "RSS Feed for Network Updates - No Longer Supported" and other stuff no longer supported. Is there any way to get latest activity ?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually for the moment being there is no way to get any social feeds from linkedin, the most you can do is get your profile data, this can be achieved by http://wordpress.org/plugins/lips/ a plugin that serves for this purpose exactly.

Hope this info helps your quest :).